# How to save file from URL to blob

Tags: javascript, html, file

I need to download .csv file using < a > tag.
Solution now works in Chrome, Firefox but not in IE, Safari.

I'm using:

```
<a download href="api url">Download</a>
```

attribute **download** is not supported by IE and Safari.

I found JS library *file-saver*, but it requires **blob** file.

Now, I need to create blob file from api url and download it using **file-saver**.

**UPDATE**:
One interesting detail: When I'm opening url directly in browser for example: *example.com/docs/files* (**without file extension!!!**). I'm getting 404 Page Not Found. But when I'm using `<a DOWNLOAD href="https://example.com/docs/files">Download</a>` it works perfectly, file is downloaded, no new page is opened

Comment: You don't need to do that. What is the file extension? If it's not a file extension that a Browser normally displays then it will download automatically.

Comment: Extension is .csv.
Description updated

Comment: You may want to look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#example-2918)

Comment: One interesting detail:
When I'm opening url directly in browser for example: [link]https://example.com/docs/files[/link] (without file extension!!!). I'm getting 404 Page Not Found.
But when I'm using `<a DOWNLOAD href="https://example.com/docs/files">Download</a>` it works perfectly, file is downloaded, no new page is opened

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not presently support the `Download` attribute on `A` tags.

See http://caniuse.com/download and http://status.modern.ie/adownloadattribute; the latter indicates that the feature is "Under consideration" for IE12.